# Defining python array size for a loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to add data on each row of a array through a for loop. For that i thought of using vstack.

but since i have two types of array (different in size) I want to define the column numbers, only the column numbers since i dont know how many rows i will have. An array with predefined NaN members, in order to have such an array after :

```
Array=
[ x , x , x , NaN,NaN] # in case size is 3
[ x, x , x , x , x] # in case size is 5
```

the code is :

```
Array=[]
forArray=[]
for line in searchlines:
    Array=re.findall(r'[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+', line)
    size=len(Array)

    if size == 3:
        [G,x,y]= Array

    if size == 5:
        [G,x,y,i,j]= Array
forArray=np.vstack((forArray,Array))
```

I tried :

```
if size == 3:
    [G,x,y, NaN, NaN]= Array
```

but is not working...........

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out what you are trying to do, but I'll critique your code

```
Array=[]      # bad name, especially when the value is a list
forArray=[]
for line in searchlines:
    Array=re.findall(r'[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+', line)
    # why did you intially set Array to []?
    size=len(Array)

    if size == 3:
        [G,x,y]= Array
        # so you are assigning the 3 values in Array to 3 variables
    if size == 5:
        [G,x,y,i,j]= Array
        # and 5 variables
forArray=np.vstack((forArray,Array))
```

In the last line, `forArray` is an empty list, `Array` has 3 or 5 values

```
np.vstack(([],[1,2,3]))
```

produces a ValueError, because there's a mismatch in the length of these 2 lists.

Why did you use `vstack`?  Up to this point you are working with lists.

```
if size == 3:
    [G,x,y, NaN, NaN]= Array

but is not working...........
```

It's not polite to say 'is not working' without saying what is wrong - wrong result, specific error message, etc?

```
[a,b,c,NaN,NaN]=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

runs fine, setting `NaN` to 5.  But with just 3 values, I get `ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack`.  That's basic Python - when unpacking you need a matching number of values on each side of the =.

What are you trying to do with this expression?

Step back from `numpy` and arrays, and try to get this working right with Python lists.